# How to route a Rails 5 API single page app with multiple static entry points?

Tags: routes, single-page-application, vue.js, rails-api

Cannot figure this out for some reason. I have a Rails 5 API app only serving JSON. I have two VueJS front-end apps, one for the public and one for private "admin."

I want to serve both of these static html files from Rails public folder. Index.html works great. But I want to route the subdomain "admin.lvh.me" to the "admin.html" page instead of index.

Yes, I'm using the "-b lvh.me" flag on Puma.

I've tried variations of this, but it never seems to serve the admin.html file:

```
root to: redirect('admin.html'), constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }
```

But its like Rails isn't paying any attention to it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect url to a public file as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match 'admin', :to => redirect('/admin.html'), via: :get
end
```